# Python doesn't detect Heroku config

Tags: python, heroku, environment-variables

From my Windows 10 command line:

```
heroku config
```

yields the output:

```
=== test-bot Config Vars
GROUPME_BOT_ID: [111111111111111111]
```

My Python 3 code:

```
  data = {
          'bot_id' : os.getenv('GROUPME_BOT_ID'),
          'text'   : "hi",
         }
  print(data)
```

yields:

```
{'bot_id': None, 'text': 'hi'}
```

The `bot_id` is `None` instead of `111111111111111111`. Why?

For testing, I execute my code from the command line of my Windows computer via:

```
python app.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`heroku:config` only sets environment variables on Heroku. To run your code locally you will have to set your environment variables locally. (They can be different in development and production. That's the whole idea—they're *environment*-specific.)

There are several ways to do this. Here are two:

- On your local machine you can use a [`.env` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#set-up-your-local-environment-variables) containing data in the format

  ```
  VAR1=value
  VAR2=value2
  ```

  and then run your application [using Foreman](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#run-your-app-locally-using-foreman), which will automatically read the `.env` file and set appropriate environment variables:

  ```
  foreman start
  ```
- You can set environment variables using something like [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/), which will read an `.envrc` file for your project whenever you `cd` into its directory and set environment variables accordingly. In this case you don't need to use Foreman; `python app.py` should work fine.

  There are editor and IDE plugins for `direnv` that can automate this in your editor as well.